# ASP.Net Core MVC Routing Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a project (Developed by using .Net Core), I have set some routes and one of them is not working e.g.

```
1) routes.MapRoute("HRDetail", "H-R/{TName}/{MId}", new { controller = "ABC", action = "XYZ1" });
2) routes.MapRoute("CL", "{SName}/{CName}/{CId}", new { controller = "ABC", action = "XYZ2" });
```

I have written the code in the same sequence in Startup class, and my action methods are as follows.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> XYZ2(string SName, string CName, Int16 CId)
{//for route#2}
public async Task<IActionResult> XYZ1( string TName, Int64 MId)
{//for route#1}
```

Now I want to hit on `XYZ1` by using route#1 and the link (to hit on `XYZ1` is being created dynamically) is like this `http://localhost:4321/H-R/UK/1234`. But the problem is that when i click on this link, it always take me to `XYZ2` method.
I didn't set any route on controller or action method level.
Is there any solution plz?

Comment: I test it in asp.net core 2.2 without any problems.Could you create a new mvc project and test again?Could you show your complete startup.cs?

Comment: @XingZou first of all, thanks for your effort. I have been working on this project from 1 month, these routes were working fine, but suddenly it started to behave abnormally... So, to get rid of this problem, I just created a new controller for this purpose and its working fine with the same route... again thanks dear...

Answer (score 1):

It seems, The route are getting confused. There are two ways you can fix this.
1) in your first route specify the regular expression which will say that first parameter will be a fixed string as H-R
2) in you second route specify the regular expression which will say that first parameter will never be H-R

1st

```
routes.MapRoute("HRDetail", "{ActionName}/{TName}/{MId}", new { controller = "ABC", action = "XYZ1" }, new{ActionName = "$your regularexpression to include only H-R$"});
```

OR

```
routes.MapRoute("CL", "{SName}/{CName}/{CId}", new { controller = "ABC", action = "XYZ2" }, new {SName = "$your regularexpression to exclude H-R$" });
```

PS: you need to put some efforts for regular expression